# how to make flex container to shrink to a smallest reasonable size?

Tags: css, flexbox, margin

I have a button, which is flexcontainer with two items.

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex
    column-gap: 1rem
    align-items: center
    margin-right: 10rem /* just for illustration sake */
    cursor: pointer

    &:hover
        opacity: 0.6
}
```

And it takes all available space in a row despite the fact that the items wouldn't stretch. The problem is that when user points to the right from the button it reacts just like if the mouse would be on the button. I would like flexbox container to end right after the 2nd item. How it do it?

[image]

`margin-right: auto` doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `display: inline-flex` which will make it a flex container that renders like an in line element.

UPDATE: - I have added a demonstration of the outcome of the two types of flex display. The important thing to realise is that the flex behaviour is on the children of the flex-container and there is no difference in their layout between the two types of flex.

The difference is on how the parent container renders in relation to the surrounding page content. With `display: flex` -the container is rendered as a block level element that has flexed children elements. With `display: inline-flex` -the container is rendered as an inline level element that has flexed children elements.

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border :solid 1px red; /* just for illustration sake */
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 8px;
    }
    

.inline-flex-container {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    border:solid 1px blue; /* just for illustration sake */
    cursor: pointer;
     padding: 0 8px;
    
    
    }
    
    
.caret {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  border-color: #000000 transparent transparent transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6px;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p>Display: flex (causes a block-level parent container and flexed children)</p>
<div class="flex-container">
  <button type="button">Button</button>
  <span class="caret"></span>
</div>

<hr/>
<p>Display: inline-flex (causes an inline-level parent container and flexed children</p>
<div class="inline-flex-container">
  <button type="button">Button</button>
  <span class="caret"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Ive accepted your answer, but I want to figure out, is which situations the result of "inline-flex" (from the viewer PoV) will be different from "width: max-content"?

Comment: Also do you know the reason why "display: inline flex" can be different from "display: inline-flex"? MDN says that they are the same and the 2nd one is legacy value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display But Chrome 94.0. doesn't understand "display: inline flex" for some reason.

Comment: Without the hyphen it would be the equivalent of display: inline; I would have thought, which is invalid styling. Glad my solution worked- happy coding 

Comment: `Without the hyphen it would be the equivalent of display: inline;` why then mdn states the opposite? they've reverted css standards?

Comment: Sorry - I don't know - I was guessing - always follow the <DN docs - they are a better src of info than me  - sorry to have put you wrong. :)

Comment: yeah, but my browser seems to be more consistent with your answer than with docs :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `width: max-content` on the flex container. That will make the container's width match its contents.

This is similar to gavgrif's answer, but this will not establish an inline formatting context. That may or may not matter for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `width: max-content`, it's also worth experimenting with `width: min-content` and `width: fit-content`. All 3 CSS properties will adjust the target element size to its content size and may achieve your desired behavior depending on the context/situation.